# Pagination with codeigniter URI issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

This is my first time working with pagination in codeigniter and I'm a little confused. I believe my problem may have something to do with the URI segments offset variable.

Here's my controller. I have replaced the `$config["base_url"]` with the full URL so you can see how many URI segments I have.

**My controller**

```
        $gutterId = $this->gutter->convertGutterNameToId($name);
        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = "http://localhost/gutter/g/random/";     //base_url() . "/g/$name";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->gutter->countThreadRows($gutterId);
        $config["per_page"] = 1;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 5;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $limit = 1;
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;

        $data['threads'] = $this->gutter->grabThreads($limit, $offset, $gutterId);
        $data['title'] = $name;
        echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

**And my model.**

```
 public function grabThreads($limit, $offset, $gutterId){
            $query = $this->db->limit($limit, $offset)->order_by('thread_id', 'DESC')->get_where('threads', array('thread_sub_gutter' => $gutterId));

            return $query->result();
        }
```

So this is giving me one result on the `http://localhost/gutter/g/random/` page which leads me to believe the query is working correctly. However, when I navigate to `http://localhost/gutter/g/random/1` I get the following 404 error

> The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to route the request to your controller.
Should be something like this:

```
$route['g/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'g/index/$1/$2';
```

Also if your page number is going to be in the third segment, do this:

```
$config[‘uri_segment’] = 3;
```

Comment: my base_url is localhost/gutter and I have `$route['g/(:any)'] = 'g/index/$1';` to remove the index.php, so would it need to look something like `$route['/g/random/(:any)'] = '/g/random/';`

Comment: That's right except no trailing slash after random. @Tony

Comment: Also your URI segment is wrong, see edited answer @Tony

Comment: URI segment is after the base so if your URL is google.com/search/page/2 , your page number segment is 3